# AVC Hardware encoding when using Remote Desktop Store App

Tags: windows-10, video, remote-desktop, encoding

I have been researching how to enable hardware encoding on my work laptop so that my remote desktop experience is a little better.

Anyway, I did some research on this and I was able to (sort of) get hardware encoding running on the laptop (the remote system). However, it only works with the standard RDP client included with windows, `mstsc.exe`

I have issues with `mstsc` when I use multiple keyboards etc, but the new RDP Store app has none of these issues. The experience with app and its features are quite good compared to `mstsc`

So anyway, I enabled these two options

```
Prioritize H264
Configure H264
```

in group policy.

[image]

To check I connected with `mstsc.exe` and I got this from the event log

`AVC hardware encoder enabled: 1, encoder name is Intel® Quick Sync Video H.264 Encoder MFT. Server: ----`

[image]

As per my research Event 170 means hardware encoding is enabled, as also stated in the Log message.

However when I connect via the Remote Desktop Store app, I get this event

`The client supports version 0xA0400 of the RDP graphics protocol, client mode: 2, AVC available: 0, Initial profile: 2. Server: -----`

[image]

The RDP store app has very little way of configuring anything for a connection.

I checked [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1533492/windows-10-remote-desktop-with-remotefx-and-hardware-h-264-using-nvidia-nvenc) which says the client needs to tell the server that it wants to use AVC, however I can't find a way to make the RDP Store App to do that!

Is there anyway I can make the RDP store app connect the same way as `mstsc.exe` ?

System Configuration : **Thinkpad L480, Intel Core i5 8250U, Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake)]**

[image: Thinkpad L480, Intel Core i5 8250U, Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake)]

Comment: "AVC available: 0" - tells me the client either does not support AVC or it's not being enabled. Have you tried perhaps a third-party RDP client that also supports AVC?

Comment: @Ramhound it works with mstsc.exe, can you suggest some 3rd party RDP clients?

Comment: `SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\AVCHardwareEncodePreferred` is set to what exactly?

Comment: @Ramhoundits set to 1 , settings currently https://i.imgur.com/zIvzZlU.png

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Store application does not currently support AVC encoding (and in general is not affected by group policies set on the machine).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks! Didn't know they didn't support it considering the age old mstsc has AVC support.